# Maximum value from Firebase Firestore collection

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

```
collection
        *
        Random_Id1
                *amount:100
                *name:John
        Random_Id2
                *amount:150
                *name:Matt
        Random_Id3
                *amount:65
                *name:Alice
```

I have  a firestore collection that has different documents under it. these documents have data within them(name,age,amount, etc.). is there a way i can return the highest or Maximum **amount** in the collection? I'm implementing this in java(android).
**In the case of the above structure, the Maximum will be 150**.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You have to use a query that is defined via a combination of `orderBy()` and `limit()`, as follows:

```
CollectionReference collectionRef = db.collection("collection");
Query query = collectionRef.orderBy("amount", descending: true).limit(1);
```

See the docs here https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries and here https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin, you can do it like this:

```
db.collection("collection")
   .orderBy("amount", Direction.DESCENDING).limit(1)
   .get()
   .addOnSuccessListener { documents ->
           //your code, print the highest amount   
   }                
   .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
           Toast.makeText(this, exception.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
           Log.i("YourActivity",exception.toString())
    }
```

Then, run your project and trigger the above call to the database. You will see a toast with a firebase exception message. Go to your Logcat, filter it with YourActivity class name, and you will see there a link to Firebase, in order to confirm this new index that you are creating. Wait for it's building a few minutes, and when it's status is enabled, run your project again.

Answer (score 0):

```html
const maxRef = await db.collection('collection').orderBy('amount', 'desc').limit(1).get();
const dataRef = maxRef.docs? maxRef.docs[0] : null;
console.log(dataRef.data())
```

[reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#order_and_limit_data)

Comment: Could you add some more information, please? What do you want to archive, for instance!

Comment: To get the row data of the max value in the amount column